# XSD Generated Class containing a System.Xml.XmlElement property

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm currently working with generating XML files used to configure a server.

I've got a class generated with xsd which contains a property of the type `System.Xml.XmlElement`.

```
public class GeneratedClass
{
    ...

    private System.Xml.XmlElement informationField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Information", IsNullable=false)]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement Information {
        get {
            return this.informationField;
        }
        set {
            this.informationField = value;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm having troubles "injecting" a custom object into this Information property.

```
public class MyExampleObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set;
}
```

The program deserializes a xml file of the type `GeneratedClass` and after this I want to add `MyExampleObject` to the `Informations` property.

The way I currently do this is with this method:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyExampleObject));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, MyObject);
        }

        this.Information = doc.DocumentElement;
```

After this I serialize the whole object to file, but when I do this I get unwanted xml namespace attributes.
`<Information xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="">`

I've found other posts with similar problems, but the suggested solutions, leaves me with `<Information xmlns="">` which is still not a complete solution.

I get the feeling that there might be some other way to do this, but I'm not sure how.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**I know that this post is very old :) But perhaps might come in handy for others seeking answer to this**

**Update** Sorry I was a bit quick reading your question and focus on my own problem which was also regarding namespaces in some sense, but more how to remove one. I see that you use `XmlSerializer` and unfortunately I don't know how to manipulate namespaces added as attribute on class to serialize. Perhaps look at `XmlRootAttribute` that you can pass to `XmlSerializer.ctor` and then you have `XmlSerializerNamespaces` which is passed during serialization and provide mean to manipulate namespaces.

I recently stumbled upon this as well and found a solution.

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
var xmlElement = xmlDocument.CreateElement(Prefix, "Document", Ns);
xmlElement.InnerXml = string.Empty;
var navigator = xmlElement.CreateNavigator();
navigator.AppendChildElement(Prefix, "InfRspnSD1", Ns, null);
navigator.MoveToFirstChild();
navigator.AppendChildElement(Prefix, "InvstgtnId", Ns, "123456789");
// At this point xmlElement contains XML and can be assigned
// to the generated class

// For pretty print only
using var sw = new StringWriter();
using var writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sw, Settings);
xmlElement.WriteTo(writer);
writer.Flush();

return sw.ToString();
```

([Code on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/joacar/dfff06823c7284147f904dd1cd5f761a))

What I've noticed is that the namespace is included twice, one in the root node and then once again immediate descendant (first child).

```
# Generate XML using XNavigator
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<supl:Document xmlns:supl="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:supl.027.001.01">
   <supl:InfRspnSD1 xmlns:supl="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:supl.027.001.01">
     <supl:InvstgtnId>123456789</supl:InvstgtnId>
   </supl:InfRspnSD1>
</supl:Document>
--------------------
```